# If a subset S of a vector space, V spans V then there exists a subset of S that also spans V. Prove?

Tags: linear-algebra

Additional related question: Can span of a subset, S of a vector space, V ever be a superset of V. Answer is No! Because V will no longer be a vector space then as V will not be closed under vector addition. Is the reasoning right?

Comment: When you use subset, do you mean proper subset?

Comment: Yes, for now. let us consider it to be a proper subset

Comment: In that case heading statement is false.

Comment: @user45409 Do you mean that there is a subset of $S$ which is a basis for $V$?

Comment: @almagest, yes, I mean we have to prove that S contains the basis of V

Answer (score 1):

As you commented that we should assume it to be a proper subset, in that case, let  $dim(V)=n$ and let $S$ is a set of $n$ elements of $V$ which form a basis of $V$. Then any proper subset of $S$ would have less than $n$ elements. Any set which has less that $n$ elements cannot span $V$ as $dim(V)=n$. Hence the heading statement is not true.

Comment: @ Prakhar Gupta, "let S is a set of n elements of V which form a basis of V". Just because S spans V it need not be true that size of S is n

Comment: But $S$ is an arbitrary subset of $V$ which spans $V$, so it can be a basis too, which has $n$ independent vectors in it. In that case, a proper subset of S which has at most $(n-1)$ elements in it, can not span $V$.